# Error Installing ruby with RVM Single User mode on Arch Linux

Tags: ruby, arch-linux, rvm

I've just installed RVM on ArchLinux x64 in single user mode via the recommended install script

`curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

I've also installed all the requirements listed in `rvm requirements`

However, I'm having trouble actually installing any version of ruby. And getting the following error:

```
arch:~ % rvm install 1.9.3
No binary rubies available for: ///ruby-1.9.3-p194.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /home/christopher/.rvm/archives
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  460k  100  460k    0     0   702k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  767k
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /home/christopher/.rvm/src
Prepare yaml in /home/christopher/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Configuring yaml in /home/christopher/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/home/christopher/.rvm/usr ', please read /home/christopher/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/yaml/configure.log
Compiling yaml in /home/christopher/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running 'make', please read /home/christopher/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/yaml/make.log

Please note that it's required to reinstall all rubies:

    rvm reinstall all --force

Installing Ruby from source to: /home/christopher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p194 to /home/christopher/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #extracted to /home/christopher/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194
Skipping configure step, 'configure' does not exist, did autoreconf not run successfully?
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #compiling
Error running 'make', please read /home/christopher/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

The log files are as follows:

```
arch:~ % cat ~/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/yaml/configure.log 
__rvm_log_command:32: permission denied: 
arch:~ % cat ~/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/yaml/make.log     
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
arch:~ % cat ~/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/make.log     
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 0):

Really looks like a permission problem somewhere , try running the

> ./configure --prefix=/home/christopher/.rvm/usr

at  /home/christopher/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4 manually in a try to get a better error log , if it's not sufficient you can try to strace the configure command.

Also if it's a fresh install you can

```
# rvm implode # (run as root)
$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```